# Why not import all dependencies everywhere?

Tags: import, sass

I followed an advanced sass/(s)css course and they explained to me the 7-1 architecture and such. It all makes sense but then the instructor refuses to import dependencies within each file and I don't understand why. The instructor simply replied "this is scalable, this is how the big boys do it so you should just do it"... But I don't understand why?

***main.scss***

```
@import "abstracts/variables";
@import "layout/grid";
```

***abstracts/_variables.scss***

```
$gutter-horizontal: 6rem;
```

***layout/_grid.scss***

```
  // Note that this file does NOT import _variables.scss
  .col-1-of-2 { width: calc((100% - #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 2); } // uses a variable from _variables.scss
```

**main** imports the other 2 but **_grid** does NOT import **_variables**. Yes, it will still work because main imports **_variables** before it imports the **_grid**.

But the part that I don't understand: What if someday I make another file called **admin-area-main.scss** that imports **_grid** but I forget to import **_variables**... Sure, this is a simple example but at some point you may have dozens of nested imports and I wonder what the point is of putting all code into their own separate files, yet, I still make them all dependent on one another and also require future programmers to know all of these dependencies? Why shouldn't I simply add @import *"abstracts/variables";* to the **_grid** file so that I can later use it anywhere?

Not adding those imports also breaks error-checking and code completion in some editors.

Note that personally, I'd probably prefer to make a **_variables-grid** file instead of one extremely large **_variables** file.

Comment: The instructor also told me to just make 1 and 1 only compiled css file for the entire project. So if I later make a forum, admin area, etc. with 100% completely different (S)CSS, then I should just dump everything into the main file and use that one globally? Erm, is that correct? It seems kinda bad but okay it would technically solve my question.